# Does page caching also cache the contents of an iframe?

Tags: iframe, page-caching

I want to activate page caching for my website. We occasionally make use of iframes which load frequently updated content - does page caching cache the contents of an iframe as well?

Comment: Normally yes. You need to reload the iframe if you want a current version. I have no idea what your website's platform is, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: We're using Wordpress and will be caching with W3 Total Cache and Cloudflare. Now that you mention this, both iframes we use are from third parties and it looks like their scripts reload the iframe already!